# Spatial data overlay selection in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, raster, r-raster

I'm trying to overlay some spatial data from a bigger SpatialPolygonsDataFrame (world size) to a smaller (country size), by doing these:

```
x <- c("rgdal", "dplyr",'ggplot2')
apply(x, library, character.only = TRUE) 

est<-readOGR(dsn='/estados_2010',layer='estados_2010')
est_f<-fortify(est)
est$id<-row.names(est)
est_f<-left_join(est_f,est@data)

zon<-readOGR(dsn='/Zonas Homogeneas/gyga_ed_poly.shp',layer='gyga_ed_poly')
zon_f<-fortify(zon)
zon$id<-row.names(zon)
zon_f<-left_join(zon_f,zon@data)     

t<-ggplot()+geom_polygon(data=zon_f,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group,fill=GRID_CODE))

t+geom_polygon(data=est_f,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group),fill=NA,color='red')+coord_fixed(xlim=est_f$long,ylim=est_f$lat,1)
```

Which is resulting in this:

[image]

I'm want to select only what is being plotted inside the polygon with the red lines.
If someone could help me with this issue, I'll appreciate

PS.: For those who want to reproduce the example completely by yourselves, the files are available in the links above to my google drive:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6XKeXRlyyTDakx2cmJORlZqNUE

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use function `over` in library `sp`

Comment: I already tried it, but only gives me a data.frame without coordinates to plot a map.

Comment: Exact. You can try `raster::intersect`. It works for two SpatialPolygonsDataFrame. Or `rgeos::gIntersection`.

Comment: Still no success
> raster::intersect(est_f,zon_f) results that answer 
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows. If I try both commands, without fortify my SPDF, also has an error, but with a different message: 
Error in RGEOSBinTopoFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, id, drop_lower_td, unaryUnion_if_byid_false,  : 
  TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 31.250011019999999 -26.083331560000001 at 31.250011019999999 -26.083331560000001

Comment: have you tried `zon_f2 <- zon_f[est_f, ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using polygons to display the raster values, you can use a spatial selection via `[` like in this reproducible example:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

bra <- getData("GADM", country = "BRA", level = 1)

r <- getData("worldclim", res = 10, var = "bio")
r <- r[[1]]
r <- crop(r, bra)

r <- rasterToPolygons(r)
# bra and raster (now as polygons) have to have the same projection, thusly reproject!
bra <- spTransform(bra, CRSobj = proj4string(r))
```

#### here comes the magic!!

```
r <- r[bra, ]
```

let's look at the results:

```
library(ggplot2)
t <- ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data=r,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group, fill = rep(r$bio1, each = 5)))
t + 
  geom_polygon(data=bra,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group),fill=NA,color='red') + coord_map()
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer helped me to solve my problem, thank you ^^. But I used a different approach, rasterising my information before insert it in the brazilian map, because it was in writen as polygons, and only after doing this I could follow your steps, but it worked anyway. A big thank you for your help =) !